# Buttons defined inside php are not visible

Tags: php

Neither of the divs and buttons defined after the while loop are visible until the timer goes down. I don't know what's the problem. I tried it outside the php also but still it shows nothing. Everything was working well before adding this php code to display a number of distinct questions selected from a database randomly. Someone please help me. I'm a newbie in php. Thanks a lot in advance.

```
<?php

$record=array(); //creating array to keep record of Q_ID of questions

for($count=1;$count <= $NoOfQuestion;$count++)// to display $NoOfQuestion number of questions
{
    while(1)
    {
        $sql=mysql_query("select * from questions order by RAND()");
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
        $temp=0;
        if(count($record)>=1)
           {
              for($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++)
              {
                  if($record[$i]==$result['Q_ID'])
                  $temp++;
              }
           }
       if($temp==0)
           {
              $text ='Question '.$count. '. '.$result['Question'];

              echo $text;
              return 0;
           }
       else
           return 1;
    }
    echo'</div>';
    echo'<div id="option"></div>';
    echo'<div id="buton">'; 
    echo'<input type="submit" name="Previous" value="previous" id="previous"/>';
    echo'<input type="submit" name="Next" value="next" id="next"/>'; 
    echo'<input type="submit" name="Review" value="review" id="review"/>'; 
    echo'<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit" id="submit"/>';

    echo'</div>';
    echo'<div id="div3">3</div>';
    echo'</div>';

    echo'</form>';
}    

?>
```

Comment: Please post your complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code....

```
echo'<div id="option"></div>';
echo'<div id="buton">'; 
echo'<input type="submit" name="Previous" value="previous" id="previous"/>';
echo'<input type="submit" name="Next" value="next" id="next"/>'; 
echo'<input type="submit" name="Review" value="review" id="review"/>'; 
echo'<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit" id="submit"/>';

echo'</div>';
echo'<div id="div3">3</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php

$record=array(); //creating array to keep record of Q_ID of questions

for($count=1;$count <= $NoOfQuestion;$count++)// to display $NoOfQuestion number of questions
{
    while(1)
    {
        $sql=mysql_query("select * from questions order by RAND()");
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
        $temp=0;
        if(count($record)>=1)
        {
            for($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++)
            {
                if($record[$i]==$result['Q_ID'])
                $temp++;
            }
        }

        if($temp==0)
        {
            $text ='Question '.$count. '. '.$result['Question'];

            echo $text;
            return 0;
        }
        else
            return 1;
    }
}

    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div id="option"></div>';
    echo '<div id="buton">'; 
    echo '<input type="submit" name="Previous" value="previous" id="previous"/>';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="Next" value="next" id="next"/>'; 
    echo '<input type="submit" name="Review" value="review" id="review"/>'; 
    echo '<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit" id="submit"/>';

    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div id="div3">3</div>';
    echo '</div>';

    echo '</form>';
?>
```